# ESP32 PubSubClient connection with self-signed certificate fails with state -2

Tags: mqtt, tls1.2, esp32

I am desperate.

I am trying to connect from an ESP32 to my MQTT broker with a self-signed certificate. The libraries in use are WiFiClientSecure and PubSubClient.

I'm using https://wokwi.com as I currently don't have access to an ESP32.
The connection keeps failing with state -2.

Here's the code:

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

// WiFi
const char *ssid = "Wokwi-GUEST"; //WiFi name
const char *password = "";  //WiFi password

// MQTT Broker
const char *mqtt_broker = "152.67.151.213";
const char *topic = "esp32/test";
const char *mqtt_username = "********";
const char *mqtt_password = "********";
const int mqtt_port = 1883;

const char* root_ca PROGMEM = \
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n" \
    "MIIDhzCCAm+gAwIBAgIUViQZNJUlRTBYRkTfljNNUN4sjZowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL\r\n" \
    "BQAwUzELMAkGA1UEBhMCTFYxDTALBgNVBAgMBFJpZ2ExDTALBgNVBAcMBFJpZ2Ex\r\n" \
    "CzAJBgNVBAoMAkxVMQwwCgYDVQQLDANTTUkxCzAJBgNVBAMMAkpUMB4XDTIyMDQy\r\n" \
    "NzE3MDQ1NVoXDTI3MDQyNzE3MDQ1NVowUzELMAkGA1UEBhMCTFYxDTALBgNVBAgM\r\n" \
    "BFJpZ2ExDTALBgNVBAcMBFJpZ2ExCzAJBgNVBAoMAkxVMQwwCgYDVQQLDANTTUkx\r\n" \
    "CzAJBgNVBAMMAkpUMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4V/m\r\n" \
    "ZNKfBEoqvHHNK4J6TiRtPKRCcGsNgZAOrAK/isJgOiJaZkJ8Ef6s2Moh4RR6GWi9\r\n" \
    "QabV9cGAcsa3MbcSzTE6pKlw6EcTmMzX3Wg2xFj4TwUJHXOzPUITvXRPl8GOQS2C\r\n" \
    "wlqbOEp7zKnKzfJ/A2nK4CkQZEEJ10AkXzfLiiw0CKHR1KNt23Y8chzfWCU89LBP\r\n" \
    "xISCSwBqofhHtN1w//Gh7SyvtGfFRb87yGPpn3ULoes5EmSkqOo3LEmNyz/3rPdB\r\n" \
    "cCNZnN6z7vk1alUgMqlsFHT48FAE/xgfBqw35VR2dUAaqIwZTyA9giLssPTizw3C\r\n" \
    "REYcIeKCXMWpqa7GRQIDAQABo1MwUTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU3ezmrWMb7sTUgMJ5JJqR\r\n" \
    "uoXF89EwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU3ezmrWMb7sTUgMJ5JJqRuoXF89EwDwYDVR0TAQH/\r\n" \
    "BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAcUHWtg2ETX5FJNnKjL5wmP+LPhE8\r\n" \
    "6VhOzXHdQgO2HTuinzZOoD0kYZ6K06loNBq2+nRcl4SEUQKiSajDcsBrFIy47R1o\r\n" \
    "8ztWbM+ALA03FKT6ezWkM75/g6wamyGFoZKQaI71UfW/LVS9AlTPRD4wfcgI6ee0\r\n" \
    "ZT6lXLv6GwnA5z1rrVKWBAbR6/6gdAPVYYj9EszTFRqnWLjHDv16zAyP18TBfYFY\r\n" \
    "7cddN4dQIUnr/gYNsI1k2pCmB0mQuObxhjq2U3p3siTmEAaNAVF1m+9+DDWy/Aar\r\n" \
    "78UuEhtf35C0b6Yj4h7xwNpAmHtikg3HTY0+pciq+bdcPA6buN+eu/eV2Q==\r\n" \
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n";
    
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 // connecting to a WiFi network
 WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
     delay(1000);
     Serial.println(".");
 }
 Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");
 //connecting to an mqtt broker
 client.setServer(mqtt_broker, mqtt_port);
 espClient.setCACert(root_ca);

 while (!client.connected()) {
     String client_id = "wokwi-test";
     Serial.printf("The client %s connects to the public mqtt broker\n", client_id.c_str());
     if (client.connect(client_id.c_str(), mqtt_username, mqtt_password)) {
         Serial.println("Public emqx mqtt broker connected");
     } else {
         Serial.print("failed with state ");
         Serial.println(client.state());
         delay(2000);
     }
 }
}

void loop() {
}
```

No publishing or subscribing is currently necessary, all I want is a connection.
The credentials are correct, I set them myself.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error -2 is [MQTT_CONNECT_FAILED](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/2d228f2f862a95846c65a8518c79f48dfc8f188c/src/PubSubClient.h#L47) which simply means your simulated ESP32 cannot connect to the MQTT host.

A short test using a mosquitto client shows that whatever is listening on 152.67.151.213:1883 is not a TLS-encrypted service. It seems to accept MQTT connections, but unencrypted. So try without the TLS (i.e. not using WiFiClientSecure) or pick another port where TLS is supported.

Comment: But when I try to connect to a different broker(i.e. test.mosquitto.org), all works well(can publish/subscribe to topics). Could the error code indicate a problem with the certificate?
Also, are separate Client Certificate and Private Key chars and inclusions needed?

Comment: OK, it would have been good to mention that from the start. Anyway, I updated my answer based on this.

Comment: I'm getting this same error of -2 on my esp32.  I have mosquitto default setup on my mac with anonymous enabled and can connect to it with an android app over wifi on the LAN.  But my esp32 fails over and over with this -2.  I didn't use any certs in the esp32, and I used WifiClient.h (not secure).  I was thinking my problem might be the opposite?  Is there a good way to get more logging out of the esp32 about the -2 cause?  Thanks for the link on the git for pubsubclient, I'll be looking there to try to see about logging also

Comment: @Eradicatore - it's probably best to post a new question with relevant details. You can raise the default log verbosity of ESP IDF by running `idf.py menuconfig` and changing [CONFIG_LOG_DEFAULT_LEVEL](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/system/log.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. 100% agree.  I added logging and that helped identify the issue in an odd way.  It showed zero activity and that reminded me that I had setup my broker and client on guest vs normal LAN.  The phone app test also helped tell me the broker did work because the phone was on normal (not guest).